# get parent state from ui-router $stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to access the name of the parent state when detecting a statechange.
My code so far:

```Javascript
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, authProvider) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log(toState.name);
    });
});
```

Returns `[parentState.childState]`. One possibility would be to use regex to replace every symbole that comes after the "." but I guess there has to be a function in ui-router to get the name of the parent state.

What would I have to add? to get `[parentState]`?

Example:
The user comes from the state `login` to the state `pets.dogs`. `pets` is an abstract parent state, `dogs` is a child of it. 
`fromState.name` would return `login` but I want `pets`.

EDIT: 
Yes, the workaround `toState.name.split(".")[0]` is possible but only works under controlled conditions.

Comment: `fromState.name` will work.

Comment: I don't want the state where the user comes from but the State the toState is a child of. 
For example the user comes from 'login' to 'pets.dogs'. 'pets' is an abstract parent state. 
`fromState.name` would return `login` but I want `pets`.

Comment: If names are relative then you can manipulate name string and find out. I don't know if there is any function available or not.

Comment: check with $state.$current.parent!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do `toState.parent.name`.

Comment: This is not working, There is nothing like parent in toState

Comment: @ojuskulkarni It depends on how you configure your states. In my application I used [this method](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#parent-property-using-state-name-string) to set the parent states.