# UI-router accessing parent state from child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to set the title based on the state in my angular app. It works nicely, but if there's no title defined on the child state, I'd like to fall back to the parent's title property.

This is what I have so far:

**In my app run block:**

```
...
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {

  if (current.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    $rootScope.title = current.title;
  }
});
...
```

**In my module's route**

```
.state('main.parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  controller: 'ParentController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'app/parent.html',
  title: 'Parent',
})
.state('main.parent.child', {
  url: '/child',
  controller: 'ChildController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'app/child.html'
})
```

During the code inspection, I found that `$stateChangeSuccess` is triggered twice as expected, first for the parent and then for the child. I tried to access `current.parent` when the child was called, but it has no such property. Is there any way to access it?

**UPDATE**

I saw these questions:
[get parent state from ui-router $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36864460/2419215),
[get parent state from ui-router $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864460/get-parent-state-from-ui-router-statechangestart)
But none of them had a clear answer to this problem (except the state splitting hack in the latter one but I'd rather avoid that).

Comment: check with $state.$current.parent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I came up with the following solution:

I store `title` inside the state's `data` object, because from `$state` you can't access the parent's custom properties, only the ones stored in `data` (which makes sense - not to pollute the state definition with custom properties).

```
.state('main.parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  controller: 'ParentController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'app/parent.html',
  data: {
    title: 'Parent'
  }
})
.state('main.parent.child', {
  url: '/child',
  controller: 'ChildController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'app/child.html'
})
```

And I changed the runblock as follows:

```
...
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, fromState) {
  var current = $state.$current;
  if (current.data.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    $rootScope.title = current.data.title;
  } else if(current.parent && current.parent.data.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    $rootScope.title = current.parent.data.title;
  } else {
    $rootScope.title = null;
  }
});
...
```

This is not the perfect solution yet, as in the case of multiple nested states it'd be nice to fall back to the title of the youngest ancestor's title but it does it for now.

Answer (score 5):

The both ways are hacks a bit. 
Don't forget to import $state (and $stateParams for 2nd variant) providers in your controller.
You can use:

```
$state.$current.parent.self.title
```

or

```
var tree = current.name.split('.');
tree.splice(tree.length-1, 1);
var parent = tree.join('.');
$state.get(parent, $stateParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just need the `title` property to fall back to the parent's title property if there's no title defined on the child state, I will suggest you to use this repository: [angular-ui-router-title](https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-title).

Answer (score 0):

Simply below code is working for me

$state.$current.parent

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the UI-Router [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#stategoto--toparams--options) in the "to" section, you could do something like below:

```
$state.go('^');
```

to go back to the parent state.